# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server. I have written below select and at the time of execution I am getting data conversion error. Please help me to identify the issue and suggest how do I fix it.

```sql
SELECT   
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(Day_GuestCount) <> 0 AND SUM(Day_ForecastGuestCount) <> 0
          THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 1), ((SUM(Day_GuestCount) / SUM(Day_ForecastGuestCount)) - 1) * 100) * -1 
          ELSE CASE 
                  WHEN AllCompanyRestaurantsClosed = 'Yes' AND StoreOwnershipType = 'Company'
                     THEN 'All Restaurants Closed (' + SpecialDateLabel + ') '
                     ELSE '(' + SpecialDateLabel + ') '
               END
    END AS 'vsExpectations',
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(Day_SRSGuestCount) <> 0 AND SUM(Day_SRSPreviousYearGuestCount) <> 0
          THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 1), ((SUM(Day_SRSGuestCount) / SUM(Day_SRSPreviousYearGuestCount)) - 1) * 100) * -1
          ELSE ' '
    END AS 'SRC',
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SUM(Day_MO_NetSalesAmount)) AS 'Sales',
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SUM(Day_MO_GuestCount)) AS 'Customers ',
    'DWDMOS' AS Report
FROM    
    [DBname].[schemaname].tablename
WHERE   
    StoreOwnershipType = 'Company'
    AND IsMobileSite = 'Yes'
GROUP BY 
    StoreOwnershipType, DayNameOFWeek, SpecialDateLabel,
    CurrFullDate, AllCompanyRestaurantsClosed
```

Columns datatypes:

```
Day_GuestCount - DECIMAL(38,4)
Day_ForecastGuestCount - DECIMAL(38,4)
AllCompanyRestaurantsClosed - VARCHAR(3)
StoreOwnershipType - VARCHAR(50)
SpecialDateLabel - VARCHAR(225)
```

Values:

```
Day_GuestCount - 0
Day_ForecastGuestCount - 0
AllCompanyRestaurantsClosed - 'Yes'
StoreOwnershipType - 'Company'
SpecialDateLabel - 'Thanksgiving'
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Please help me to identify the issue and fix .

Comment: *"I am using SQL SERVER 2012"* but you tag [tag:sql-server-2016]; what are you actually using?

Comment: As for the error, what don't you understand about it? It *is* telling you the problem.

Comment: Looking at your SQL, you have a `CASE` expression that tries to return a `decimal(5,1)` in one `THEN` and a `varchar` (`'All Restaurants Closed (' + SpecialDateLabel + ') '` in another. The latter is clearly *not* a `decimal(5,1)

Comment: A `CASE` expression in T-SQL **must** return a single atomic value from each of the various alternate routes - and it **must be** the **same datatype** for all possible return values. That's not the case in your situation - and then SQL Server will try to convert the "diverging" data according to the datatype precendence list - and `decimal` is higher than `varchar`, so SQL Server tries to convert your string to a `decimal` and fails ...... fix that - all alternatives in a `CASE` must return the **same datatype**

Comment: For data integrity, database tables and query resultsets do not support mixed types. It is unclear why you are trying to mix percentage/ratios and varchar indicators in *same* column.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the reply. So you recognize the issue that's really great. But This is as per my business requirement and I cant change the code. Can you please suggest any fix or bypass so my code will work.

Comment: If you can't change the code, you can't fix the error ....